# MVC 3 + Episerver =?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, episerver

Is it possible to use ASP.net MVC 3 in the latest version of Episerver?

Comment: fwiw, I want to know this. :(

Comment: Yes.  You can use Mvc with EPiServer 7